# Difference between Java SE app and Java EE app?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, 3d

I want to create a 3D application in the Netbeans IDE, and I'm wondering if I should create a Java Application (Java SE) or an Enterprise Application (Java EE). Also, is there any libraries that I should add to my game that would make 3D things easier?

Comment: ok, then. I was going to do that anyways, cause thats what I've always used :)

Comment: [light-weight-java-game-library](http://lwjgl.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I should create a Java Application (Java SE) or an Enterprise Application (Java EE).

It depends on what it is, and where it is intended to be executed.

- A free-standing Java application is typically built as a Java SE application.
- An application that runs on a server is typically a Java EE application.  (The client could be a web browser, or a separate client application, which is likely to be a Java SE application.)
- An application that runs on a mobile platform might be a Java ME application (various flavours), or an Android application.
- Then there are JavaFX applications, Flash applications, Applets ...

A "game" in the general sense could be implemented in any of those ways, depending on what is it does what the UI is supposed to be like, and so on.

Obviously, for a highly interactive (3-D or not) game, you would not want client / server round-trips in the loop.  (That would result in "network lag" and "poor gaming experience").  The computational and data intensive 3-D modelling and rendering needs to be done close to the users graphics board.

On the other hand, if your game is multi-player, you do need to communicate the player state to other players ... somehow.  And there are some aspects of game play that you might want to do on a server to avoid cheating by "modding". It is not unreasonable to use Java EE in those parts of the problem.

> Also, is there any libraries that I should add to my game that would make 3D things easier?

Calls for recommendations.  That's off-topic.  Please do your own research and make up your mind what *your* application needs.  (Besides, "3D things" is a very broad topic.  It is too broad for meaningful recommendations ... )

Comment: +1 for the helpful answer. Though I decided to add another one, because I thought it is not stating strong enough that JEE isn't the right choice here.